# App rejected: 17.2 - Apps that require

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store, privacy

```
Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected
```

My app new version rejected and old version already in apps store that also have same thing but why they rejected in this version . what i need to do .app have a resignation form there user is proving a email,mob, password,gender.

Comment: I think Apple's rejection description is self-explanatory. So, what's the question? Sure you may _like_ to capture that information, should the user choose to volunteer it, but you can't require it. And just because the old app was accepted doesn't mean they have to accept the new app...

Comment: but app need to use gender and email

Comment: I'd suggest you consider ways to make the app offer some basic functionality in the absence of identifying information. If that's not possible, perhaps edit your question to explain why, precisely, the combination of both email address and gender is required for the app to function properly.

Comment: @Sport i have faced same issues but after explain about my app they accepted .

Comment: Give the user options of registering or not registering your app instead of forcing them to do so.

Comment: @Sport did you get any response ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem like you , 2 times

**1 st time :-** I used registration same like you, then i have changed my application's flow. made registration as optional. and they accept it .

**2 nd time :-** I replied to apple that , **"please clarify me regarding rejection issue ,sorry, but i can't able to understand why my app rejected ?"** I can't do anything and application will be live on 2nd or 3rd day.

**So, my opinion is** , 1st ask to apple to clarify rejection issue in detail. if your luck then it will be live. or wait for their replay and then modify your application according to their replay.

**Edit:-** When you upload the app on App Store and your app include "Personal information from users -> Example registration" , try to provide "why you need personal detail" or application's flow in description .

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i have faced my app rejected due to we are getting phone number and email id like that.

What you have to do now is ,reply them like this .

1.To contact customer we are getting user information ,there is no illegal purpose in it.

like that you need to explain about your app.

Don't worry they rejected your app for getting information about your app purpose ,explain it clearly .